# How to design context-free grammars generating the languages with twice as many a’s as b’s?

Tags: context-free, language-design

The problem is designing context-free grammars generating the following languages.

The set of strings over the alphabet Σ = {a, b} with twice as many a’s as b’s.
I found a solution but I don't know how to get this.

S → SS | aaSb | bSaa | aSbSa | $\epsilon$

Comment: I just found that this solution is incorret....   S can not produce "bbaaaa". I edited it.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking if there is a formula or algorithm to automatically generate a grammar for a particular language?

Comment: @tjhighley  Just design the context free grammar for this problem~

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. Could you ask a more precise question? (Actually, could you ask a question at all? There are no literal questions in your post and I can't understand what is the question you're trying to imply.)